# Should we migrate this (closed) duplicate question to ELL?

Tags: discussion, migration

The question [Word to describe the list of people that I have a crush, love, and lust](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/382397/word-to-describe-the-list-of-people-that-i-have-a-crush-love-and-lust) was closed here as Primarily Opinion Based. Meanwhile, the asker cross-posted the [nearly identical question to English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/124645/a-common-word-or-group-or-description-of-all-the-following-love-lust-crush-i) (and added a bounty). It is apparently on-topic there. The OP has not responded to my request that they comment on what, if anything, was wrong with the answers that accumulated here before the question was closed.

I was a little bit tempted to copy my answer over, but that seems...not in the spirit of the thing. I can't find very much about this topic, but the up-voted comment on [this Meta question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237835/when-a-question-is-cross-posted-should-the-answer-be-cross-posted) (there is no upvoted answer) suggests that perhaps our version of the question should be migrated to ELL, where it could then be merged with the version there.

So, can/should we migrate the question? And a secondary question, if we do, is there anything special that needs to be done to get them merged?

(And a third question that just occurred to me: It's probably too late for any such action to affect the bounty, but if it's not should we delay until after the bounty closes?)

Comment: FWIW, I didn't really like the question there either. [Damkerng sums up my stance on this pretty well](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/124645/a-common-word-or-group-or-description-of-all-the-following-love-lust-crush-i#comment253670_124645). Cross-posting is frowned upon, but it's too late for that now. I think a migrate and a merge, if not hindered by system restrictions, is the best thing to do here. The other option is deleting the one on ELU but then you'd have to post your answer to the ELL one yourself; extra work. (And definitely don't copy your answer to two threads)

Comment: Here's an idea. delete your answer on EL&U, the chances of the OP being reopened here are very slim. Copy and paste your answer on the ELL page where it belongs, that way no effort has been wasted, there aren't two identical answers, and ...everyone is happy. I think. Yes, why not?

Comment: I tell a lie it has 3 reopen votes. It stands a chance of being reopened. The mods should intervene. The OP broke the guidelines, he only cares about getting his single-word answer. How selfish and inconsiderate of him. I don't know what to suggest now.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Agreed, it's an annoying situation. I wasn't tempted to cross-post so much because I think my answer's great (it's not) as because of my annoyance with the whole thing. My actual first (unpublished) answer was along the lines of "no, there's no word, because anyone with any sense would realize that these categories of 'relationship' shouldn't be lumped together." I reigned in my snarky self to try to give an actual answer, but now I'm sort of sorry I did.

Comment: I should add that my comment about his apparent selfishness was said tongue in cheek. Of course, he cares only about getting an answer, he needs to create that computer folder pretty urgently :) You did well to reign yourself, we don't know him, we shouldn't judge a book by its cover. Still... he seems to be quite a frisky sort of chap.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Yes, virtually all askers only care about getting an answer; it's the nature of the beast, and as it should be. I don't know why this particular situation got my goat enough to post on Meta.